# Connecting with the Azure SFTP ApiApp Connector

Tags: azure, sftp, azure-web-app-service

I have been playing around with the Azure SFTP connector for API Apps and Logic Apps (under the new preview site (portal.azure.com)) but have not had much luck getting it to work.

The Connector requires the following package settings to be set: ServerAddress, ServerPort, SSH Server HostKey, Root Folder, Accept Any SSH Server HostKey (bool), and Encrypt Cipher. It does not ask for a user name, and after activating the API app and attempting to use it I get the expected response of HTTP 400 with:

```
[
  "User Name Value cannot be null, empty, or cannot contain only white-space characters."
]
```

The Swagger api definition does not define any way to pass in the username and I cannot see anyway to define it in the connector settings, does anyone know how to set the username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the user and pass at the security component in your App API panel, select it an then you can set the user and password.

[image]

[image]

Check this url for more info: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-connector-sftp/

Comment: It looks like MS updated the documentation shortly after my post, however I now seem to run into the same problem that you have posted to the azure forum. Did you ever end up resolving the SFTP connection problem or is it still ongoing?

Comment: Yes, the problem is it still ongoing. There is a new connector version 0.0.400, but the update button doesn't work, I have the 0.0.378. Create a new SFTP Connector and put it in a Logic App is impossible to me because everytime the new portal fails creating connector or configuring SFTP Connectors. :-(

Comment: Marking this answer as correct as it answers the question, lets just hope that MS fixes the other problems soon so we can get to using it.